# How to bring particles on the upper side of a character's face

Tags: particles, faces, hair

My character's face is a bit thick and curvy when creating hair particles, they come on the lower side of the face, and I want them to be on the upper side of face instead.

## Blend File

[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YZLihba1SnCOWol0skYV4-sS9vbJn34s)

Comment: Please provide blend file. Your information is too less

Comment: Done I have added a google drive link

Comment: there is no particle system at all in your blend file

Comment: but maybe your problem is, that you didn't apply your scale : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckBDK.png

Comment: @Chris Please now check the link

Answer (score 1):

if you apply your solidify modifier, the particles will be outside like this:

[image]

And as @Blunder said, the even better way is to check the "Use modifier stack" checkbox in the particle settings, because it is a non-destructive way of doing this.

[image]

Comment: I prefer to tick *Emission > Source > [X] Use Modifier Stack* in the particle settings. So you can keep the modifier on the stack and it's non-destructive.

Comment: @Blunder: yeah, you are totally right. I improved my answer.